# Probing assembly in .net

Tags: .net, probing

I know that how `CLR`[probing assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but I want to know:Is `CLR`probing assembly  in `GAC` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLR will check the GAC prior to using the probing hints.  The full details of the order in which assemblies are found are [located on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Basically, once the CLR knows which assembly (including version) needs to be found, it sees if it's loaded already, then checks the GAC, then probes using the probing hints.