# How do I distribute program compiled with cmake for windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, windows-installer, software-distribution

So I've made a c++ program that compiles with msvc and cmake, and I'd like to run in on another computer.

When I transfer the executable to that computer,but when it starts it's saying that some dlls are missing. I probably need to install/configure some libraries, on which the program depends.

Is there an automated way that would compile an msi file that would install on the target system everything that I need?

Comment: Please see these previous answer: **`1)`** [Determining dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940598/129130), **`2)`** [Debugging applications failing to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530377/129130). Most likely you just need [the visual studio runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). And finally [my messy deployment link collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) - all kinds of links, but a real mess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what dlls you application needs. One way to check is with dependency walker found [here](https://www.dependencywalker.com/)

[Here is a newer](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) version of it, haven't tried it