# The operation could not be completed. Error loading type library/dll .Net

Tags: windows, xaml, c#-4.0, windows-installer, exe

I have a xaml C# project which is a windows .exe application. I want to create a setup file for the same so that I can install it on other machine. I have followed this link to create MSI setup. [Creating installer setup](https://medium.com/@kanchanaj/how-to-create-a-windows-installer-setup-file-for-desktop-application-using-visual-studio-2017-beb13015fb58)

From the above link when I am on Step 4 under (Procedure to create Setup file:) it throws error "The operation could not be completed. Error loading type library/dll". Infact if I try to add or delete any thing from section File System on Target machine, it throws same error. I am using VS 2015

if anybody faced same error Please help.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Is that just .NET Core you need? I don't use it yet. Maybe search for answers from Chris Painter - he has some stuff on that topic. Or just Google it. Here is one page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: no its not .net core

Answer (score 0):

***Deployment Tools***: [Quick review of MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) (free and commercial) - see if there is one to better match your needs and requirements.

***Deployment***: To solve the application problem, please find some links below. IT might be something as simple as an `error in your configuration file` or a `lacking runtime`.

- [**Tools for dependency scan / deployment debugging**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940598/129130) (find what files should be deployed)
- [**Application launch debugging**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512998/desktop-applicaton-not-opening-after-installation-in-client-system/53530377#53530377)

---

***Further Links:***

- [Deployment link collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)